# Collecting data from different workers in a multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a case where I need to collect data from multiple sources and I would like to do this using multiprocessing, but I cannot collect the data gathered by the workers. It's a complicated process so here's some code to get the logic:

```
import pandas as pd 
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool as pl

logger = mp.log_to_stderr()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) 
 
def pool_handler(wkList):
     with pl(8) as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(self.func, p) for p in wkList]
     return results
        
 def read_csv(iFiles, imTime, delim):
    logger.info(f'Reading data that are prior to {imTime.isoformat()}')
    dfClean = None
    headers = ['DataFormat', 'Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute']
    dtypes = {'DataFormat': 'Int32', 'Year': 'Int32', 'Month': 'Int32', 'Day': 'Int32', 'Hour': 'Int32', 'Minute': 'Int32'}
    # read in the data with correct dtype and build date time group (dtg). Each should return a dataframe
    wkList = [ (i, imTime, delim, headers, dtypes) for i in iFiles ]
    ret = self.pool_handler(wkList)
    return ret

def func(self, iargs):
    logger.info(f"checking file: {iargs[1].isoformat()} <=> {iargs[0]}")
    df = pd.read_csv(iargs[0], names=iargs[4], sep=iargs[3], dtype=iargs[5])
    return df
```

This code works but `ret` doesn't contain the dataframes, `df` from all the workers.

Comment: Since every worker runs the same function, why not simply use `results = pool.map(self.func, wkList)`?

Comment: @RolandSmith I'm new to multiprocessing in python. What is the advantage here you are hinting at?

Comment: Using `pool.map` is simpler; you don't have to gather the results manually.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `pool_handler` to this:

```
def pool_handler(wkList):
    with pl(8) as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(self.func, p) for p in wkList]
        results = [rs.get() for rs in results]
    return results
```

`apply_async` returns an [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object which acts similar to a promise. You must retrieve the actual result using the `get` function before closing the pool to do what you want to do.

**Edit**: There seems to be an error in your original code. `func` accepts one tuple as an argument, but if you supply a tuple to `apply_async`, it will automatically unpack its values to the target function. Therefore, you should alter your code to supply the arguments inside another tuple (so it gets unpacked as a single argument):

```
results = [pool.apply_async(self.func, (p, )) for p in wkList]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But when I tried it I got an error saying the function `worker` takes 1 argument not 5. This error occurred on line: `results = [rs.get() for rs in results]`.

Comment: @Shejo284 Check the edit. As a sidenote, this is an error that was happening in your original code as well, but you were not aware of it because all errors encountered in the worker functions are only raised after doing `.get()`.